# Pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, mongoose

Does anyone know why I'm still receiving a deprecation warning even though I've already specified `useUnifiedTopoology: true` in my `MongoClient` constructor?

Thank you in advance!

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const connectionURL = 'connectionurl'
const databaseName = 'db'

const client = new MongoClient(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const insertHandler = async(data, collectionName) => {
  await client.connect().then(async() => {
    const collection = client.db(databaseName).collection(collectionName)
    await collection.insertOne(data)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("Failed to insert:", error)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  insertHandler: insertHandler
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the
new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology:
true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: restart server and try again

Comment: @kedarsedai I've brew stopped and run the mongoDB again but the warning is still there.

Answer (score 13):

**You can do it this way**

```
var mongoDb = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongoDb.MongoClient;
var serverUrl = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
var dbName = "sample_db";

mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
   // Code goes here...
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Mongoose for MongoDB, the same code with no error. `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YOURDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used and it worked for me:

```
const mongoServer = require('mongodb');
const mongoClient = mongoServer.MongoClient;
const dbName = 'tconnect';
const serverUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

// Create a database
const dbUrl =  serverUrl + dbName;
const client = new mongoClient(dbUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

client.connect( (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Database successfully created!');
        db.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think your method worked when compared to the one in the question? Could you expand a bit the explanation for your answer?

Answer (score 3):

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vidly',
{ useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(()=>{ return console.log("Connected to MongoDB Localhost...");
 })
.catch(err => console.log("Could not connect",err))
```

It's working for me!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just note a few points for your next answer: (1) Properly format your code. It just makes it easier for OP and other uses to quickly understand the solution. (2) Try to add more details about your answer and link proper sources if available.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it, and this is the solution which worked:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way, and I don't see that warning anymore.

```
const run = async () => {
await mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
};
run().catch(error => console.error(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8169

> this is the reference to solve this problem

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const GITHUB_ISSUE = `gh8169`;
const connectionString = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${ GITHUB_ISSUE }`;
const { Schema } = mongoose;

run().then(() => console.log('done')).catch(error => console.error(error.stack));

async function run() {
  console.log('Mongoose version:', mongoose.version);
  mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
  mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
  mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useFindAndModify: false });
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  
  db.once('open', () => console.log('connected'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as below:

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });